# Set up correct relative path across my site and in php-include functions

Tags: php, path, relative-path, absolute, php-include

I have a basic question and since I am a noob with php it is difficult to dig through the thousands of questions you already answered...So I ask you for further help, sorry...

I just need to recall `header.php` into HTML pages. The website structure look like this:

```
-index.php
-header.php
-style.css
-articles/article1.php
-image/header.jpg
```

For `index.php` I used

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

and everything works fine!
The problem arises with pages like `article1.php`, i.e. for pages that are not in the root. I tried with

```
<?php include ('http://localhost/phpBB3/header.php'); ?>
```

because I am working locally rightnow, and 'localhost/phpBB3' is the root)
but it does not work.
Also I tried with

```
<?php include ('/header.php'); ?>
```

or with

```
<?php include ('../header.php'); ?>
```

barely understanding the real meaning of all these `./` (I know, I know, shame on me!)

Moreover, the `header.php` points to both `style.css` and `header.jpg` (the latter inside the `image` folder) and refers to ids and classes defined, of course, in the `style.css`.
I think I may have some problem in their path as well.

How can I put things in order?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Mya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `http://localhost/phpBB3/header.php` does not work is because PHP's `include` requires a local path. You can achieve what you want with `dirname( __FILE__ )`.

`include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../header.php';`

More on [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

More on [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#constant.file)

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I must admit that the php manual is above my level. What do you suggest in case I would set everything for the remote server?

Comment: Is `dirname ( __FILE__)` mandatory? Why `'/../header.php'` alone does not work? thanks in advance

Comment: `__FILE__` is a constant that represents the full local file path to whatever PHP file the constant is used in (e.g. `/var/www/myfile.php`). `dirname()` will take any path and strip the filename part off of it (e.g. dirname( '/var/www/myfile.php' ) == '/var/www' ). You can use them both as in the example above to include PHP files relatively. I would recommend always including files relatively like this, that way the includes will work no matter if you are on a local server or production server.

Comment: `'/../header.php` does not work because it is ambiguous. If you have nested includes for example, should PHP include the file relative to the one that started the include or relative to the one being included now? To resolve this ambiguity, `__FILE__` always points to the current file (e.g. the file being included in the case of nested includes). That is why it is needed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob this is a very clear explanation. Now there must be something wrong in how the `header.php` recall the `style.css` and the `header.jpg` relatively to the `article1.php` in the example. Adding `dirname(__FILE__)` let appear just the ALT tag of the header image and nothing else. No style at all. In the `header.php` the stylesheet is called as `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and the header image as `<img src="image/header.jpg" alt="bikexperience.it" usemap="#Map" />` . What is wrong with such paths? Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Luckily, on the remote server it works as you suggested! In `stylesheet.css` and `header.php` all URLs to background, images &Co include `http://`. This is the only way it works..